# how to copy laravel project folder to NTFS?

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel and trying to copy my project folder to NTFS HDD but symlink are not supported and when I try:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

I get the following error:

> symlink(): Operation not permitted

which I understand means that is NTFS does not support symlinks so how to solve this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15439#issuecomment-408036822

Comment: @zerkms it did not work.. I am on ubuntu and no homstead